# Android - Obtain list of supported mobile network types

Tags: android, networking

I'm trying to identify an API within the Android OS which returns me the list of supported mobile network technologies for that phone.

For example:

- A OnePlus 5 would return: `2G`, `3G`, `4G`
- Whereas a OnePlus 9 would return: `2G`, `3G`, `4G`, `5G`

There already has to be something within the OS as the settings screen can populate this, as per screenshot:

[image: mobile network type selection modal]

Similarly, the debug activity `Phone info`, launched via `*#*#4636#*#*`, populates a drop-down with similar options. This type of data is equally good as well, as either option can then be parsed accordingly.

[image: Phone info network type dropdown]

Again, not clear where my own app could fetch such data from.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I came across an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.novvia.fispy) that solves (almost) similar requirement.

While I do not have the code with me, I would have tried to inspect into `NetworkCapabilities`  [more info here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getNetworkCapabilities(android.net.Network))

You will have to dig deep inside `NetworkInfo` class

Comment: Thanks. It seems that there is no official way around it, and maybe via reflection one might have some luck.

I'll explore a bit more, and if I find answers I'll update here.